# How to remove a suggested email that shows in "To" field?

Tags: 8.1-update-1, email

I was showing to my daughter that you can send emails by appending *"+something"* just before the *"@"*.

Unfortunately **Windows Phone** is remembering this bogus e-mail I had type and suggest every time I start to type my daughter's name.

How can I remove this bogus email from the suggest list?

Answer (score 3):

Curiously this doesn't seem to be a "feature" yet. There is a proposal on the [Windows Phone Uservoice Site](https://windowsphone.uservoice.com/forums/101801-feature-suggestions/suggestions/2810505-clear-e-mail-autocomplete-history) you should check out (and vote for). The only way at the moment to get rid of those suggestions is doing a hard reset.

Other things I've tried that ***don't*** work:

- Clearing temporary files
- Doing a soft reset of the phone

Comment: I've tried [this](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-ecoms/misspelled-autofill-email-address-on-my-windows-8/9e9998fc-ac88-4193-8733-2ea824c648f2?Ocid=Windows-Phone-Support_Social_TWITTER_WinPhoneSupport_20150223_150125873&linkId=12520593) too and now I have one more bogus email.